# How to pass dynamic value to $http.post in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Here is the scenario, I have a "Get course" button in the page when i click of the button, i'm passing courseId, In  getCourse() method am returning $scope.courseId; then i'm passing this variable in $http.post method. but when i debug in developer tool i'm not getting courseId value.

```
    $scope.getCourse= function(){ return $scope.courseId;}

    $http.post('js/description.json', $scope.courseId).success(function(data){       
             $scope.response = data;        
    })
```

if i pass static course id like below, i'm getting the course id, so please suggest how to pass dynamic value.

```
    $http.post('js/description.json', {'courseId':'Adobe'}).success(function(data){       
             $scope.response = data;        
    })
```

Comment: why dont you use 'js/description.json', {courseId:$scope.courseId}

Comment: that's fine, you can pass directly like $scope.courseId or {courseId:$scope.courseId} it doesn't matter, but i'm having issue only at the time of dynamic variable.

Comment: Could you explain further, what you mean by "dynamic"?

Comment: sure, assume i have this below link, on click of this link i need to pass the value of "Adobe" to server using $http.post, along with the json/serverlet url.
<a ng-click="getCourse(Adobe)">Get Course</a>

Comment: could you set up plunker of code what you have tried

Comment: check this out: 
http://jsfiddle.net/qb9RC/

Comment: See answer I posted. Put your `$http.post(...)` in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$scope.getCourse= function(){ return $scope.courseId;}` returns the `Course Id`. You could use

```
$http.post('js/description.json', {courseId: $scope.getCourse()}).success(function(data){       
         $scope.response = data;        
})
```

However, if you are passing `Course Id` into the method that does the post, you use

```
$scope.getCourse = function(Id){ // Id is passed into function
    $http.post('js/description.json', {courseId: Id}).success(function(data){       
         $scope.response = data;        
    });
}
```

Comment: Still no luck for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot ur method worked pretty fine, thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are just passing the string "Adobe" instead of the object that the service expects.  Try:

```
$http.post('js/description.json', {courseId: $scope.courseId}).success(function(data){       
             $scope.response = data;        
    })
```